# Why $L2$ loss is strictly convex if number of samples $N$ is larger than input dimension $d$?

Tags: linear-regression, loss-function

I am using $L2$ loss in my linear regression problem and I have to prove that my $L2$ loss is strictly convex if number of samples $N$ is larger than input dimension $d$.

I think, if I can prove that my hessian matrix, $ X^T X $ for $L2$ loss is positive definite then that will do. Here, $X$ is the feature matrix with  $N$ samples as rows and  $d$ columns.

Also, I understand $v^T X^T X v$ $\ge 0$,

as,  $v^T X^T X v$ = $(Xv)^T. Xv$ = $|| X.v ||^2_2 $ (Which is the euclidean norm of $X.v$) i.e hessian matrix is positive semi-definite.

But I don't understand how to prove $ X^T X $ is positive definite or $L2$ loss is strictly convex.

-please ignore the constants in $L2$ loss.

Comment: This question needs more context

Comment: @yoav_aaa verify it again once please

Answer (score 1):

I think an additional assumption of linear independent inputs is necessary to have a strictly convex loss function. 
Linear independence with $N>d$ gives you $Xv \neq 0 ~ \forall v \neq 0$, which implies that $X^\top X$ is positive definite, as $||Xv||_2 > 0 $.

Comment: I also reached the same conclusion, but couldn't find any source to verify it. Could you please suggest some source I could refer for more clarification? -Thanks

Comment: For which part of the conclusion can't you find a source?

Comment: If $N>d$ then, it doesn't make or does make the columns of $X$ linearly independent.

Comment: All one can say for sure is, that for $N < d$, $X$ will not be linearly independent. For $N > d, $X$ could in principal be both. That's why in my opinion, you would need the additional assumption, that it actually is independent.